# CSS curtains, it rimains opened when the site is runned up

Tags: javascript, html, css

As u can see, my curtain is open every time u first run up the site. The curtain opens when u click Account and closes when u click it again. I need to have the curtain closes and open only when someone clicks Account. Then, I need also that, when u click Account, the world became of the gradient of the background and the background himself get white.

```js
function open_ac_c() {
        document.getElementById("ac_c").style.height = "100%";
        document.querySelector('button.account_open_button').style.display = "none"
        document.querySelector('button.account_close_button').style.display = "block"
    }

    function close_ac_c() {
        document.getElementById("ac_c").style.height = "0%";
        document.querySelector('button.account_open_button').style.display = "block"
        document.querySelector('button.account_close_button').style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #6f0da8;
    margin: 0;
}
.topnav {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #2c8a86, #1dada7, #04d6ce, #00fff6);
    padding: 30px;
    float: center;
}

.home {
    background-color: transparent;
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 18.5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.home:hover{
    background-color: #048b59;
}

.account{
    background-color: transparent;
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 86px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 18.5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.ac_curtain {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ac_curtain a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

.account_open_button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 28px 53px;;
}

.account_close_button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 30px 53px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <dive class="home">Home</dive>
  <dive class="account">Account</div>
</div>

<div id="ac_c" class="ac_curtain">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Log in</a>
    <a href="#">Log out</a>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="open_ac_c()" class="account_open_button"></button>
<button onclick="close_ac_c()" class="account_close_button"></button>
```

Comment: For starters you got some typos like `dive` != `div` but I don't see any curtain effect you speak of also.

Comment: Yes, there is an e that has not to be there. I remove the curtain effect because I don't want a background bhinde it. But, if u run the code, u can see that if u click Account the curtain hides and if u click it again the curtains come out. the problem is that Is out even if i didn't click Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On initial load, as the height of `ac_curtain` is not defined, hence it has a default height and thus it gets displayed on the initial load. Please add `height: 0` in the `ac_curtain` class.

```js
function open_ac_c() {
    document.getElementById("ac_c").style.height = "100%";
    document.querySelector('button.account_open_button').style.display = "none"
    document.querySelector('button.account_close_button').style.display = "block"
}

function close_ac_c() {
    document.getElementById("ac_c").style.height = "0%";
    document.querySelector('button.account_open_button').style.display = "block"
    document.querySelector('button.account_close_button').style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #6f0da8;
    margin: 0;
}
.topnav {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #2c8a86, #1dada7, #04d6ce, #00fff6);
    padding: 30px;
    float: center;
}

.home {
    background-color: transparent;
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 18.5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.home:hover{
    background-color: #048b59;
}

.account{
    background-color: transparent;
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 86px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 18.5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.ac_curtain {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.ac_curtain a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

.account_open_button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 28px 53px;;
}

.account_close_button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 30px 53px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="account">Account</div>
</div>

<div id="ac_c" class="ac_curtain">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Log in</a>
    <a href="#">Log out</a>
    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="close_ac_c()" class="account_close_button"></button>
<button onclick="open_ac_c()" class="account_open_button"></button>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now it works as it was supposed. Can u explain why? But, I need to click two times on Account for show the curtain and, when I want to hide it, there is like 1sec. of delay after the click.

Comment: Hi, It works on a single click in the code snippet I have added. You need to move the button with the click method `close_ac_c` above the button with the click method `open_ac_c`. Also, the above code snippet does not have any delay when hiding.